# Служба postgresql была запущена и затем остановлена

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Привет. ОС Windows 7. Установил СУБД Postgres Pro 9.6. Не запускается служба postgrespro-X64-9.6. Входит окно что служба postgrespro-X64-9.6 была запущена а затем остановлена. Искал решение в гугле, не нашел. Подскажите в чем проблема, как исправить. В программирования новичок.

Comment: Видимо, что-то мешает серверу запуститься. Смотрите, не пишет ли он чего подозрительного в свои логи. Ну и в системных событиях тоже посмотреть не помешает, он может и туда сообщать об ошибках.

Answer (score 0):

Может поможет кому.
В Windows при установке PostgreSQL создаётся пользователь postgres. 
При возникновении подобной ошибки добавьте пользователя postgres во вкладку "Безопасность" папки C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL и дайте ему все права.
После этого служба запускается нормально.

Comment: ЕМНИП, это не единственная причина. Та же ошибка появляется, если БД не инициализирована (после установки постгреса надо выполнить скрипт, который создаст БД). Правда, я уже 10 лет с постгресом не работал, не помню.